# Views HTML List displays empty random regions

Tags: views

I created a View with a HTML list format showing Rendered entities.
The first row displays 3 items properly, the 2nd row displays only 1 item, rows 3&4 are good, row #5 displays only 1 item...

You may see it at: http://dtodonline.com.au/30nYj/product-index

Would you know how to not have those "empty slots"?
Thanks

Comment: please include screenshots of your views settings

Answer (score 0):

Not able to access your URL. May be it is because of width of the item. Adjust the width of the items, it will display properly for you.